# How to compare html of ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm receiving div as response from ajax request ,

I'm trying to compare the inner html of that div ,

```
<div>Blocked</div>
```

and with jq

```
success : function(msg){
   if(m.html() == 'Blocked'){
     alert('Blocked');
   }
}
```

but it gives an error

```
msg.html is not a function
```

what is wrong?

Comment: `msg.html is not a function` is unlikely to be the error as you don't reference `msg.html` in your code - is it always just a single word in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the response from your ajax request is string, so you can use string method.
you can use [includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) to check if the string inside have some specific string.

or in jquery you can try this:

```
success : function(msg){
   if(msg.includes('Blocked')){
     alert('Blocked');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is a string, so you cannot use jquery function html() to it.

You have to use string functions to get your code. Like

```
var message = msg.substring(
   msg.lastIndexOf("<div>") + 1, 
   msg.lastIndexOf("</div>")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
success : function(msg){
   if($('<div/>').html(msg).text().trim() === 'Blocked'){
     alert('Blocked');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your data came in response must be a string rather than a selector. I mean the 'msg' may look like 'SOmething.

So if your data comes in this format,then you can't use html() on string as there is no such methods in string type.

So,the answer will be something like this.

```
success : function(msg){
     if(msg)
     {
       var msg = $(msg).text()
       if(msg == 'Blocked')
        alert('blocked');
     }
 }
```

Hope.this will work.